# Creating a dynamic form, but how to do the query?

Tags: jquery, sql, coldfusion

I've created a dynamic form which allows you to modify the amount of input fields you need. This is because they may have 15 band members and need 15 fields, or one band may have 2. The only I problem I have is when submitting the form, each input is named as "memberName1", "membername2" etc. which is done using jQuery. How would I run a check while/before running the query to see if those fields are filled and if they are to input their values into the database? Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

I was thinking something like the code below. But I would need to run a loop to count through all the present fields where the name is `memberName`, followed by a number. Rather than stopping at the first empty field, run through them all. If the value is  blank do nothing. If it's got a value then insert it into my table.

```
<cfquery datasource="exampledatasource" name="insertbandmembers">
  Insert Into members(members_name)
  Values (memberName#i#)
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Use html5 required attribute <input type="text" name="usrname" required> but its not working in IE and Safari

Answer (score 1):

Uses a static number loop but breaks once a number in the sequence hasn't been passed. You could also count the number fields in jQuery and pass it along with the form submission

```
<cfquery datasource="exampledatasource" name="insertbandmembers">
  INSERT Into members(members_name)
  VALUES
  <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="15">
    <cfif structKeyExists(form, 'memberName#i#') AND len(form['memberName#i#'])>
      <cfif i neq 1>, </cfif>
      ( <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form['memberName#i#']#"> )
    <cfelse>
      <cfbreak> 
    </cfif> 
  </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

Comment: if you put the number of fields in a hidden form field and loop to the value of the field it wouldn't break.  `to = "#form.numberOfFields#"`

Comment: you forgot your end ) surrounding the member name value.  also that insert multiple rows query isn't supported by every dbms.

Comment: yes if numberOfFields is provided the cfelse and cfbreak would be removed. query syntax is mysql

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="ThisElement">
    <cfif left(ThisElement, 10) is "memberName">
       <cfset ThisValue = form[ThisElement]>

       <cfif len(ThisValue)>
           <cfquery name="AddRecord">
              Insert Into members(members_name)
              Values 
              ( <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ThisValue#"> )
           </cfquery>
       </cfif>  <!--- len(thisvalue) --->

    </cfif>  <!--- left(ThisElement, 10) is "memberName" --->
</cfloop>
```

Comment: i'm still in favor of adding the number of fields to a hidden form field and loop to the value. it could easily be updated in the jquery as the fields are added.

Comment: We all have our own opinions. I acknowlege yours but don't share it.  I think that's an unnecessary complication.

Comment: I'm not sure how looping over an entire form structure is easier than setting a variable but ok. :) we can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

*(This started out to be a comment, but it is too long .. )*

There are different ways to approach it. My preference is the one [Travis mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857537/creating-a-dynamic-form-but-how-to-do-the-query/14858413#comment20828854_14858413). Basically have jquery store the total number of members in a hidden form field. Then use that value to loop through the member fields, validate the values, and insert as needed.

You could easily adapt [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859684/104223) or [jamckinn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14858413/104223)'s example to do this. Notice they are using `<cfqueryparam>` to help guard against sql injection? Also, since these are related inserts you want to wrap the whole thing inside a single `<cftransaction>`. That ensures the inserts are treated a single unit. Either they all succeed or they all fail - together.

```
    <cfparam name="form.totalFields" default="0" >

    <cfloop from="1" to="#val(form.totalFields)#" index="x">
        <!--- extract current name --->
        <cfset memberName = trim(FORM["memberName"& x])>

        <!--- insert NON-empty values --->
        <cfif len(memberName)>
            <cfquery datasource="exampledatasource" name="insertbandmembers">
                INSERT INTO members ( members_name )
                VALUES 
                ( 
                   <cfqueryparam value="#memberName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
                )
            </cfquery>
        </cfif>
   </cfloop>
```