# Turn multiple cfif's into a cfloop(form values)

Tags: jquery, html, sql, sql-server, cfml

I need to change a static set of cfif's into a cfloop, so as to make it possible to cover all possible scenarios however unlikely. So if they happen to add 20 licenses it will not cut off the last few that I didn't manually write.

```
<cfquery name="AddLicenses" datasource="#datasource2#">
<cfif IsDefined("form.State_1") AND len(#form.State_1#) GT 0>
INSERT INTO PreceptorsLicenses VALUES 
(#Session.PreceptorID#, '#form.State_1#', #form.LicenseExpMonth_1#, #form.LicenseExpYear_1#)
</cfif>
<cfif IsDefined("form.State_2") AND len(#form.State_2#) GT 0>
INSERT INTO PreceptorsLicenses VALUES 
(#Session.PreceptorID#, '#form.State_2#', #form.LicenseExpMonth_2#, #form.LicenseExpYear_2#)
</cfif>
<cfif IsDefined("form.State_3") AND len(#form.State_3#) GT 0>
INSERT INTO PreceptorsLicenses VALUES 
(#Session.PreceptorID#, '#form.State_3#', #form.LicenseExpMonth_3#, #form.LicenseExpYear_3#)
</cfif>
<cfif IsDefined("form.State_4") AND len(#form.State_4#) GT 0>
INSERT INTO PreceptorsLicenses VALUES 
(#Session.PreceptorID#, '#form.State_4#', #form.LicenseExpMonth_4#, #form.LicenseExpYear_4#)
</cfif>
<cfif IsDefined("form.State_5") AND len(#form.State_5#) GT 0>
INSERT INTO PreceptorsLicenses VALUES 
(#Session.PreceptorID#, '#form.State_5#', #form.LicenseExpMonth_5#, #form.LicenseExpYear_5#)
</cfif>
```

Comment: What are you trying to loop over? The numbers 1 to 20? Your question needs more explanation.

Comment: Its going to loop as long as there are more fields that are filled out. So instead of having 1-whatever number, it would be a variable and just one insert statement in the loop.

Comment: So, you want to loop over the form fields named `state_n`? Also, please note that you are going to need to do much more validation  than is reflected here; you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Which part of this exercise are you struggling with? You only show us the "before" code, not any attempt you've made to work it out yerself. Do you know how to loop from 1 to n? Do you know how to extract what n will be? Do you know how to access variables with dynamically-set variable names? Which part(s) can't you do? What have you tried?

Comment: Also, did you search the archives first? How to loop through dynamically named form fields is a pretty common question. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979332/coldfusion-insert-multiple-form-fields-with-one-submit  . Since that particular question was already answered several times over, voting to close as a duplicate.
 and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857537/creating-a-dynamic-form-but-how-to-do-the-query

Answer (score -1):

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset count = 10>
<cfquery name="AddLicenses" datasource="#datasource2#">
<cfloop from="1" to="#count#" index="i">
    <cfif IsDefined("form.State_#i#") AND len(form["State_#i#"]) GT 0>
    INSERT INTO PreceptorsLicenses VALUES
        (#Session.PreceptorID#, '#form["State_#i#"]#',#form["LicenseExpMonth_#i#"]#, #form["LicenseExpYear_#i#"]#)
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
</cfquery>
</cfoutput>
```

Please note that the above code is still vulnerable to SQL injection and susceptible to other issues such as exceeding the permitted size of SQL that can be sent to the SQL Server.

Comment: A) While it is technically valid, it is preferable to explicitly specify the the target column names B) There is no need for cfoutput tags. Any variables within the cfquery will be evaluated automatically. C) True databases typically put a limit on the size of sql statements. However, it is unlikely this particular query will exceed it as it seems to use numeric values and few columns/iterations. Alternatively, it could also be executed as separate queries instead.  Though either way - it should be wrapped in a transaction to ensure data integrity.

Comment: *the above code is still vulnerable to SQL injection* True. How about showing them the "correct" way to do it ? :)

Comment: if i rewrote the code how i think it should be done the poster would not have a clear example that answer the crux of his question. Same reason I also did not show SQL Server ROW Constructor Syntax.

Comment: The above may answer the question asked, but as written it is a poor example. Explaining things in terms of the original code is fine, but demonstrating the correct way to do something is even more helpful in the long run. It benefits not just the asker, but the next guy that comes across this thread searching for answers.

Comment: if you have the time just submit your own more elaborate answer detailing the perfect implementation and be done with it.